# Ubuntu server installation with root only?

Tags: server, system-installation, root

I'm trying to replicate locally the kind of image VPS providers (DigitalOcean, Vultur, etc) gives me when I deploy on their services. To my knowledge, their base images are pretty vanilla, so I though the official ubuntu server images would be just perfect to boot in Virtual Box and I'd be done with it. Problem is: the official image forces me to create a sudo user.

This is great in a normal usage, but when I spin an instance on a VPS, I'm starting only with `root` as user. Is there any way to make an installation without sudo user with the official ISO image? (I'm open to a Vagrant Box is there is one too!)

Please note:

- I know running on `root` user is bad, I'm only doing it locally, "for science";
- I know I can `sudo su` from my user, but this is not what I want;

Again, I want to have it like they give it to me with the VPS providers... But thanks for your concerns on security ;-)

Comment: You could simply unlock the root account (by setting a password for it) and delete your standard sudo user account after the installation. I don't know how complex it would be to modify an installer image that way, but the manual method is definitely much simpler and also shouldn't take long.

Comment: @ByteCommander you're right. I too often neglect the easy solution that's sitting in front of me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Kickstart](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/installation-guide/amd64/apb.html) configuration to disable creating the user at installation.

There is an option for that : `#d-i passwd/make-user boolean false`

[Kickstart](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/installation-guide/amd64/apb.html) will be able to help you create VPS like images on different servers, it is usually used to install server's that are exactly alike.

Answer (score 6):

This is a step-by-step example of how to do it by enabling root and deleting the user, as mentioned by user *Byte Commander*

- ssh into the installation as the user `USERNAME` created during installation
- `sudo su` to become root
- `passwd` and then password to give the root user a password
- `nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config` with the following edit to allow root user ssh login

  - Find the (commented out) line `#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password` and without modifying it, add the following new line below it
  - `PermitRootLogin yes`
  - `Ctrl-X`, `y`, `Enter` to save the changes and exit nano
- `service ssh reload` to reload the ssh daemon configuration
- attempt to log in via a new ssh session as root, in order to verify if all is OK.

At this point:

- `cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd` should list `USERNAME` as the last entry.
- `cut -d: -f1 /etc/group` should list `USERNAME` as the last entry.
- `id` (when executed as `USERNAME`) should return `uid=1000(username) gid=1000(username) groups=1000(username),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),108(lxd)`

Now delete the user `USERNAME`:

- `deluser --remove-home USERNAME` to delete the user created during installation. You will get a warning `Warning: group 'USERNAME' has no more members.`, but this group will also be deleted automatically before the command finishes.

At this point:

- No user named `USERNAME` should be listed in `cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd`.
- No group named `USERNAME` should be listed in `cut -d: -f1 /etc/group`.
- It is possible to log in via ssh as the user `root` with the root password.

While it may be the case that some stuff still refers to `USERNAME`, the way the system is at this point comes relatively close to what a VPS would offer, hopefully close enough to do some testing with `Ansible` or similar.

While that *Kickstart*-solution should be the correct one, this one may be easier to archive and offer nearly the same functionality.